# Updated one column but 'published_at' column was also updated? [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In the database I have a table '**articles**' with columns: '`title`', '`body`', '`published_at`', '`image_name`' (and there are also Laravel's '`created_at`' and '`updated_at`' columns).

Here is my migration for creating **articles** table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->string('image_name')->nullable;
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

and my **Article.php** looks like this:

```
class Article extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'published_at', 'image_name'];
   protected $dates = ['published_at'];

   public function setPublishedAtAttribute($value)
   {
       $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($value);
   }

   public function getPublishedAtAttribute($value)
   {
       return new Carbon($value);
   }
...
```

I wanted to update column '`image_name`' for every record in the database (in the **articles** table) except the one with *id=18*. So, in **Tinker** I did the following:

```
 DB::table('articles')->whereNotIn('id', [18])->update(['image_name' => 'pic1.jpg']);
```

and now '`image_name`' is '**pic1.jpg**' everywhere except the row where *id=18*.

But, the problem is that this also updated '`published_at`' column, so now date & time for every record in the database are the same (except where *id=18*).

Why did this happen? I have *Accessors* & *Mutators* defined but if I understand well - they should not do anything because this command was explicit and it is related exclusively to updating '`image_name`' column?

Comment: no needs to define accessors for field when you check it in  `$dates` property of a `Model` [proof](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), Laravel cast this field automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey its not laravels problem.

May be your in your database you have timestamp so it will automatically change date.

Just change

```
$table->timestamp('published_at');
```

to

```
$table->dateTime('published_at');
```

and then refresh your migration.

Comment: I already have dateTime for published_at but always it got updated with any update query of the model (like updated_at field), example am updating just a status field I got :

message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'published_at' cannot be null (SQL: update `news` set `status` = 1, `published_at` = ?, `news`.`updated_at` = 2019-07-26 09:03:43 where `id` = 1)

If I set to nullable it clear the published_at value..